# Byobu MONITORED_TEMP displays 35000C instead of 35C

Tags: byobu

The temperature sensor that byobu uses by default is on the motherboard so I would like to have it display the temperature from coretemp instead. I have this temperature at `/sys/devices/virtual/thermal/thermal_zone1/temp` but it returns the temperature in thousandths of a degress and byobu displays this value directly when I set `MONITORED_TEMP=/sys/devices/virtual/thermal/thermal_zone1/temp` in my statusrc file so I end up with 35000C instead of 35C. Is there another location I can pull this temperature from or can I configure byobu to divide the result by 1000 before displaying it?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Found my answer in the [source code](https://github.com/dustinkirkland/byobu/blob/master/usr/lib/byobu/cpu_temp). If `MONITORED_TEMP` matches `*temp*_input` it will be divided by 1000 so updating my config to use the hwmon path instead of thermalzone solved the problem:

`MONITORED_TEMP=/sys/class/hwmon/hwmon1/temp1_input`

Comment: So your CPU is not powered by a thermo-nuclear reaction?